# adding a relative value per group in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df =pd. DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
                  'C' : [2,3,4,9,12,12,17,13]})
```

I would like to add a new column New, equal to C value/ C value where B= 'one' per group(group by A), the output would like:

```
A   B   C   New
foo one 2   1
bar one 3   1
foo two 4   2
bar two 9   3
foo three   12  6
bar three   12  4
foo four    17  8.5
foo five    13  6.5
```

My code is

```
grouped = df.groupby(['A']).head(7)
grouped['new']= grouped['C']/df[grouped['B']=='one']['C']
```

output is not I expected:

```
A   B   C   new
foo one 2   1
bar one 3   1
foo two 4   NaN
bar two 9   NaN
foo three   12  NaN
bar three   12  NaN
foo four    17  NaN
foo five    13  NaN
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Post it as text, formatted in code blocks or code fences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mapping:

```
one = df.query('B == "one"').set_index('A')['C']

df['new'] = df['C'].div(df['A'].map(one))
```

Or `groupby.transform`:

```
df['new'] = df['C'].div(df['C'].where(df['B'].eq('one'))
                         .groupby(df['A'])
                         .transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
     A      B   C  new
0  foo    one   2  1.0
1  bar    one   3  1.0
2  foo    two   4  2.0
3  bar    two   9  3.0
4  foo  three  12  6.0
5  bar  three  12  4.0
6  foo   four  17  8.5
7  foo   five  13  6.5
```

Comment: The groupby transform method is amazing. What does transform('first')do here?  df['C'].where(df['B'].eq('one')).groupby(df['A'] should come out 3 values, only 1 value per group. I tried without the transform part, it didnt work out, I just dont understanding why.

Comment: @Lilly `transform` maintains the original shape by duplicating the output values for each row of a group.

Answer (score 0):

First, set up a new dataframe which just consists of rows where B == 'one':

```
df2 = df.loc[df['B'] == 'one',:]
```

Then merge these two dataframes on the A column:

```
df.merge(df2, left_on = 'A', right_on = 'A')
```

```
     A    B_x  C_x  B_y  C_y
0  foo    one    2  one    2
1  foo    two    4  one    2
2  foo  three   12  one    2
3  foo   four   17  one    2
4  foo   five   13  one    2
5  bar    one    3  one    3
6  bar    two    9  one    3
7  bar  three   12  one    3
```

Your new column is just column "C_x" divided by "C_y". You can clean up the column names as required. Also, if the order of the rows in df is important, you probably need to reorder the output as `merge` sorts the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If `B == one` are always on top of all groups, use follwing code:

```
df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0])
```

output:

```
0   1.00
1   1.00
2   2.00
3   3.00
4   6.00
5   4.00
6   8.50
7   6.50
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

If `B == one` are not always on top , use follwing code:

```
(df.set_index('B')
 .groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: x/x.loc['one'])
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

make result to `new` column